# How to use a string in the array_intersect_key function in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm currently working on comparing keys from multiple arrays, and the amount of arrays can vary, but I would of cause like it to be fully automatic.

I've tried to make the array's I need into a string in a for loop, and then use the string in the array_intersect_key, but I can't make it work.

My input code is (not sure what that "if" statement is doing there, but that part sure works)

```
$arr = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if($key == "load" || strpos("id",$key) !== false){
        continue;
    }
    $data = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=C5DF6B05C9770667C1E3138EE69A8301&steamid='.$value.'&format=json');
    $json = json_decode($data, TRUE);
    array_push($arr,$json);
}
```

And my problem is somewhere here

```
$r = "";
for($n=0;count($arr) != $n;$n++){
     $r.= '$arr['.$n.']["response"]["games"],';
}
$r = substr($r, 0, -1);
$r = array_intersect_key($r);
print_r($r);
```

I would like this to be something like

```
$r = array_intersect_key($arr[0]["response"]["games"],$arr[1]["response"]["games"],$arr[2]["response"]["games"]);
```

with the possibility to be infinite (which is why the loop is there), but instead I get the error
"Warning: array_intersect_key(): at least 2 parameters are required, 1 given in *URL* on line 39".

If anybody knows how I can do this, possibly in another way I'd really appreciate the help

I'd like the final result to be an array with all the matching keys.

Comment: I've updated the code with my input data, but since it's copied just from my source (I'm kinda busy), there's not a specific input, but and example can be found at http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=C5DF6B05C9770667C1E3138EE69A8301&steamid=76561198057976676&format=json

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this.

```
$r = "";
for($n=0;count($arr) != $n;$n++){
   $r[$n]['response']['games'] = $arr[$n];
   $allowed[] = $n;
}
$r1 = array_intersect_key($r, array_flip($allowed)); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($r1);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Ehm... That "pre" thing was pretty smart, thx. But well, the rest does not exactly work, it now just prints the (for now) 3 arrays I have, as array 0-2, but I'd like it to become a single array, containing the matching keys